# Issue Updating Flask In Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, flask

I have a problem where I am unable to update my flask from VS code where it came as `version 1.1.2` and I need it to be `2.3.2` so I can follow along the documentation.
The flask documentation requires `flask --app hello run` but it won't run when I type that in the terminal as the option '--app' doesn't exist.

Here are the results when I type `flask --version`:

```
Python 3.9.13
Flask 1.1.2
Werkzeug 2.0.3
```

Also, if you know, I'm not quite sure why my Python version is `3.9.13` when I set up the virtual environment to be `3.11`. So if you have an answer for that it'd be appreciated.

So far, I've tried the following:

- using `pip install flask 2.3.2` which did install, but the version still showed as `1.1.2`

Comment: _when I set up the virtual environment to be 3.11_ Did you **activate** the virtual env?

Comment: Yes, but just to make sure we are talking about the same thing. I selected the interpreter with cmd + shift + p to be 'Python 3.11.3 ('.venv':venv)

Comment: I meant when you typed the `flask --version` command.  When you typed that, were you in a shell where you had **activated** the virtual env?

Comment: Yes, though I still had the same results when doing the 'Flask --version'.

Comment: Hello, after tinkering with my files for a while. I figured out the problem. I had to run the command 'pip install --upgrade Flask' in the env. Apparently, I had multiple virtual environments, and I'm still new to how to move through directories, so that wasn't helpful for me. Regardless, thank you for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.